How to fix or disable usb port cannot enable
I'm using ubuntu server 22.04 LTS, when I plug in my usb-c dongle, it starts to continuously print
usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

I'm using the dongle to connect my ethernet cable and I could access the internet but it kept printing the above
How can I fix this issue or stop it from printing? the dongle consist of 1 Ethernet port, 1 HMDI, 1 usb-c, 3 usb-a
lsusb gives the below result
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


Bus 002:Device002 is indeed a USB Hub.  Is the USB port in your PC/laptop etc where it's plugged in Blue or White?

The USB port I plugged in is a USB type C. I don't see any color?

Disconnect every device but the hub.  Does the Error still spam?

Yes it does. I only have the hub plugged in

Post the output of sudo dmesg | grep err with the hub and only the hub plugged in  See here for why.  We're looking for a negative error number.
